# What happens to named pipes in Windows when creating process exits?

Tags: windows, pipe, named-pipes

Scenario: process creates pipe with `CreateNamedPipe()` and connects to it with `ConnectNamedPipe()`, transfers some data, then exits (with no cleanup).  Does the pipe persist?  Does the other side of it, which is opened in a different process with `CreateFile()`, error out when the creating process exits?

More generally, what is the lifetime of named pipes?  How should stale pipes be cleaned up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipes are kernel objects, they stay alive until *all* handles on them are closed.

You are likely to get ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE if the client doesn't say goodbye nicely and the other process keeps using it anyway.

Comment: One important special case: if the pipe is between a parent process and a child process, and the parent inadvertently allows the child process to inherit *both* handles, then you won't get ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE, you'll just deadlock.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: How do you open the pipe between parent and child set up (both handles) before the child is created?  And how do you prevent the child from inheriting one but not the other?  This is very interesting, could you post some sample code?

Comment: @AlexI: use CreatePipe to create both ends of an anonymous pipe, you can choose to make the handles inheritable here.  Use SetHandleInformation to make the handle to the parent end non-inheritable.  After you've created the child process, close the original handle to the child end.  Sample code can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx